# Power Query - M Language: Sum with Group By for multiple columns

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I'm looking to write a DataTransform for an imported csv file which performs the following:

- GroupBy: State
- Action: Sums all columns

The Input data looks like:
[image]

The output I'm looking for would show a row each State, a column for each date, and the sum for that date.  Just using the Table.Group and List.Sum, I'm able to get this for specific dates:

```
= Table.Group(#"Change Dates to Num", {"Province_State"}, {{"4/19/20", each List.Sum([#"4/19/20"]), type number}, {"4/20/20", each List.Sum([#"4/20/20"]), type number}})
```

I don't know how many dates are in the input though so I'm looking for this to do this for N columns:

```
= Table.Group(#"Change Dates to Num", {"Province_State"}, List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"),4), (DateList) => {DateList,each List.Sum(Table.Column(#"Change Dates to Num",DateList)), type number}))
```

The above gives me the correct number of columns and rows but the List.Sum is not right.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click select both **County** and **County_Region** then right click Remove columns...

That just leaves **Province_state** and all the date columns

Click select **Province_state** and then right click  Unpivot other columns

Now you just have three columns, **Province_state**, **Attribute** and **Value**

Click select **Attribute** then Transform...Pivot Column....  Choose **Value** as the Value Column and leave other options as is

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"County", "Country_Region"}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"Province_State"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: This works great.  The trick I was missing was the Unpivot and then Re-Pivot at the end.